# Saving only processed images in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

my paperclip setup is

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100"},
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['BUCKET'],
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
    }
```

I don't want to have size limitations, since it will hassle the user to resize his/her images.
so, I put styles in for medium and thumb. 
However, the original file is still saved in s3.

How do I avoid saving the original image?

Comment: did you try that http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=90118#p90118 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback to destroy the image after the processing has been completed. This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/755593) contains an example